# How to obtain percents of two sums directly from a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

Im calculating the percent of men and woman in my database using first this query:

```
SELECT sum(case when `gender` = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as male
     , sum(case when `gender` = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as female
FROM userinfo 
WHERE id in (10,1,5)
```

Then in php i calculate the percents. But I wonder, is there a way to get directly the percents from the query?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT sum(case when `gender` = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as male
     , 100*sum(case when `gender` = 'M' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as malepct
     , sum(case when `gender` = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as female
     , 100*sum(case when `gender` = 'F' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*) as femalepct
FROM userinfo 
WHERE id in (10,1,5)
```

... assuming you don't run this over an empty rowset (division by zero)

If you e.g. want to replace invalid (division by zero) values by -1 use

```
if(ifnull(count(*),0)>0,100*sum(case when `gender` = 'M' then 1 else 0 end)/count(*),-1) as malepct
```

Comment: Is there a way to check before the calculation to avoid the div by zero?